# Asp .NET Dropdownlist Empty After Form Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` that is filled dynamically after two `textboxes` being filled.
When I submit the form, the `dropdownlist` it's empty even after being filled dynamically.

**DropDownList**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListReason" runat="server" CssClass="span8">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a reason" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Render**

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
 {
     //get the data list.
     foreach (var item in dataList)
     {  
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(this.DropDownListReason.UniqueID, item.Id.ToString());
     }

     base.Render(writer);
 }
```

**Jquery**

```
//get the data
   $.each(response, function (key, value) {
      if (value.requiresDescription) {
         requiresDescription.push(value.id);
      }

      $("#<%= DropDownListReason.ClientID %>").append($("<option />").val(value.id).text(value.description));
   });
```

*The form submmit action it's a button on click event.*

How can I persist the `dropdownlist` data after the form being submited ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the DropDownList in code behind also. The backed does not know you filled it with javascript, so when you perform a PostBack the page is reloaded and original state is restored, which is no ListItems.

So either add all the options in the DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListReason" runat="server" CssClass="span8">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a reason" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or add them programatically

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListReason" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="span8">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a reason" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

DropDownListReason.Items.Insert(DropDownListReason.Items.Count(), new ListItem("Option 1", "1"));
DropDownListReason.Items.Insert(DropDownListReason.Items.Count(), new ListItem("Option 2", "2"));
```

Now when you submit the page you can read the value of `DropDownListReason` with `DropDownListReason.SelectedValue`. This retaining of form values across PostBack is called `ViewState`. If you're gonna work with webforms you should read up on that.